# Why doesn't Alt+Enter fullscreen work in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Did Microsoft change how fullscreen works? Previously, when clicking on a windowed game in Windows 8, it went automatically full screen. Now it stays windows. Which is fine, except I can't find a way to make it go full screen. Alt+Enter maximizes it but I still see the chrome and the action bar. What am I doing wrong?

I have a Nvidia graphics card if that is of relevance

Comment: ALT+ENTER never did what you describe, if it did, then it was a function of that specific program.  The keyboard shortcut you mention has not changed since Windows 7.  Why don't you just enable fullscreen mode within the program's settings?  The shortcut does the following "Open the properties for the selected object" that is all it does or ever did.

Comment: @Ramhound: ALT+ENTER to fullscreen a window is a common Windows shortcut - possibly just a convention, but one that Microsoft themselves used - dating back to at least Windows 95 and possibly to 16-bit Windows versions. It was frequently used for things like making a DOS program (running in a window) fill the screen, but was also used on many 32-bit programs. In fact, as of Win8.1 (I'm not on my Win10 box at the moment) it still works as an alternative to F11 to put IE11 in fullscreen mode.

Comment: @CBHacking - I can only tell the author what Microsoft says it actually does.  I can tell you it does not place Chrome into fullscren mode, only F11 does that, so IE11 goes into fullscreen mode for a different reason.  [I can provide the keyboard shortcut list if you want.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/126449)

Comment: That's for Explorer specifically, not Windows in general. Of course, that's true of all keyboard shortcuts; programs can override anything except CTRL+ALT+DEL. Whether MS put it on that list or not, ALT+ENTER is a common shortcut for "toggle full screen", in fact a number of my games use it too (though I haven't tried them on Win10).
 
That comes back to the actual question, which seems to be "Why does Win10 still show window chrome when a game tries to go full screen"? As you say, the game is processing the shortcut, so Win10 is displaying "full screen" mode differently for some reason.

Comment: I think the OP was saying that the taskbar and running programs are still visible at the bottom of the screen, not that he/she was trying to affect Chrome. Alt+enter indeed toggles fullscreen/windows mode **for applications that support it** and it is disable-able via e.g. DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER

Comment: @Yorik - Which is my entire point.  The keyboard shortcut itself, has not changed, since it was introduced.  Of course `DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER` is only valid for Direct32/DirectX applications that implement it.  The behavior has not changed, without a specific example of where it does not work ( the application name ), I can't really explain it personally.  Every application where it does work, still works, on Windows 10 for me personally.

Comment: I have observed the behaviour both in Battlefield 4 and Dragon Age 3 Inquisition

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/81823/alt-enter-switches-between-window-and-full-screen Alt-Enter works in x86 (32bit) programs to switch between windowed and fullscreen, as of 10 years ago. :)

Comment: Just to add to this; I've never known the Alt+Enter shortcut to do full screen (not a big gamer) and trying it now on Edge on W10 it doesn't work.  But it does fullscreen World of Tanks Blitz (which is why I was searching) so I think it's not a *Windows* convention but maybe a *games* convention.

Answer (score 2):

Alt-Enter does **not** work for chrome (nor any other browser), as said above in the comments, it **only** works on microsoft related stuff (for example cmd). IF you're looking for something to work like that, **use F11**.

**Edit**: It works for some games too.